# Postfix is sending SPAM and I don't know why

Tags: 20.04, postfix

My server is sending spam through the whole world since yesterday and I don't know why. It looks like phishing mails for netflix.

```
grep -H -i "sent" /var/log/mail.log
```

has this entries

```
/var/log/mail.log:Dec 13 14:07:34 v220200481250113989 postfix/lmtp[2695997]: 548F081B44: to=<info@MYDOMAIN.TLD>, orig_to=<support@MYDOMAIN.TLD>, relay=mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.23, delays=0.22/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <info@MYDOMAIN.TLD> qO3tIRYS1l8/IykApp9Wtg Saved)
/var/log/mail.log:Dec 13 14:07:41 v220200481250113989 postfix/lmtp[2695997]: C674181B44: to=<info@MYDOMAIN.TLD>, orig_to=<support@MYDOMAIN.TLD>, relay=mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.19, delays=0.18/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <info@MYDOMAIN.TLD> yIsbOx0S1l8/IykApp9Wtg Saved)
/var/log/mail.log:Dec 13 14:07:57 v220200481250113989 postfix/lmtp[2695997]: C9CAB81B44: to=<info@MYDOMAIN.TLD>, orig_to=<support@MYDOMAIN.TLD>, relay=mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.17, delays=0.15/0/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <info@MYDOMAIN.TLD> 4M4qOi0S1l8/IykApp9Wtg Saved)
/var/log/mail.log:Dec 13 14:08:50 v220200481250113989 postfix/lmtp[2695997]: 2CF2481B44: to=<info@MYDOMAIN.TLD>, orig_to=<support@MYDOMAIN.TLD>, relay=mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.13, delays=0.06/0.06/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <info@MYDOMAIN.TLD> MF0VEmIS1l8/IykApp9Wtg Saved)
```

This is my main.cf

```
# This file was automatically installed on 2020-07-26T22:12:31.069482
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
myhostname = mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD
myorigin = $myhostname
mydestination = $myhostname
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
biff = no
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
unverified_recipient_reject_code = 550

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 52428800
recipient_delimiter = +

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

## Proxy maps
proxy_read_maps =
        proxy:unix:passwd.byname
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-domains.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-domain-aliases.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-aliases.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-relaydomains.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-maintain.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-relay-recipient-verification.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-sender-login-map.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-spliteddomains-transport.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-transport.cf

## TLS settings
#
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = ${config_directory}/dh2048.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:$data_directory/smtpd_tls_session_cache
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes

# Disallow SSLv2 and SSLv3, only accept secure ciphers
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, MD5 , DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, eNULL
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, MD5 , DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, eNULL

# Enable elliptic curve cryptography
smtpd_tls_eecdh_grade = strong

# Use TLS if this is supported by the remote SMTP server, otherwise use plaintext.
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = EXPORT, LOW

## Virtual transport settings
#
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-domains.cf
virtual_alias_domains = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-domain-aliases.cf
virtual_alias_maps =
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-aliases.cf

## Relay domains
#
relay_domains =
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-relaydomains.cf
transport_maps =
    proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-transport.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-spliteddomains-transport.cf

## SASL authentication through Dovecot
#
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

## SMTP session policies
#

# We require HELO to check it later
smtpd_helo_required = yes

# We do not let others find out which recipients are valid
disable_vrfy_command = yes

# MTA to MTA communication on Port 25. We expect (!) the other party to
# specify messages as required by RFC 821.
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes

# Verify cache setup
address_verify_map = proxy:btree:$data_directory/verify_cache

proxy_write_maps =
    $smtp_sasl_auth_cache_name
    $lmtp_sasl_auth_cache_name
    $address_verify_map

# OpenDKIM setup
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:12345
non_smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:12345
milter_default_action = accept
milter_content_timeout = 30s

# List of authorized senders
smtpd_sender_login_maps =
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-sender-login-map.cf

# Recipient restriction rules

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
      reject_unknown_sender_domain
      reject_sender_login_mismatch


smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
      permit_mynetworks
      permit_sasl_authenticated
      check_recipient_access
          proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-maintain.cf
          proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-relay-recipient-verification.cf
      reject_unverified_recipient
      reject_unauth_destination
      reject_non_fqdn_sender
      reject_non_fqdn_recipient
      reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname




## Postcreen settings
#
postscreen_access_list =
       permit_mynetworks
       cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_spf_whitelist.cidr
postscreen_blacklist_action = enforce 

# Use some DNSBL
postscreen_dnsbl_sites = 
    zen.spamhaus.org*3
    bl.spameatingmonkey.net*2
    bl.spamcop.net
    dnsbl.sorbs.net
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 3 
postscreen_dnsbl_action = enforce 

postscreen_greet_banner = Welcome, please wait... 
postscreen_greet_action = enforce

postscreen_pipelining_enable = yes
postscreen_pipelining_action = enforce

postscreen_non_smtp_command_enable = yes
postscreen_non_smtp_command_action = enforce

postscreen_bare_newline_enable = yes
postscreen_bare_newline_action = enforce
```

and this is my master.cf

```
# This file was automatically installed on 2020-07-26T22:12:31.069815
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_proxy_filter=inet:[127.0.0.1]:10024 
  -o smtpd_proxy_options=speed_adjust
dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog

tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o tls_preempt_cipherlist=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
  -o smtpd_proxy_filter=inet:[127.0.0.1]:10026
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

# Modoboa autoreply service
#
autoreply unix        -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags= user=vmail:vmail argv=/srv/modoboa/env/bin/python /srv/modoboa/instance/manage.py autoreply $sender $mailbox

# Amavis return path
#
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n    -       n       -       -     smtpd 
        -o content_filter= 
        -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8 
        -o smtpd_delay_reject=no 
        -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject 
        -o smtpd_helo_restrictions= 
        -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= 
        -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject 
        -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining 
        -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions= 
        -o smtpd_restriction_classes= 
        -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8 
        -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0 
        -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001 
        -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000 
        -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0 
        -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0 
        -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks 
        -o local_header_rewrite_clients=
```

cat /var/log/mail.log | grep "postfix/smtp"

```
Dec 13 16:41:19 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: warning: hostname mail-cy1gcc01bn2027.outbound.protection.outlook.com does not resolve to address 52.100.19.27: Name or service not known
Dec 13 16:41:19 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: connect from unknown[52.100.19.27]
Dec 13 16:41:19 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[52.100.19.27]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Dec 13 16:41:19 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: NOQUEUE: client=unknown[52.100.19.27]
Dec 13 16:41:23 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724352]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 13 16:41:23 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724352]: 6FD7481B44: client=localhost[127.0.0.1], orig_client=unknown[52.100.19.27]
Dec 13 16:41:23 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724352]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 xforward=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=6
Dec 13 16:41:23 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: proxy-accept: END-OF-MESSAGE: 250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6FD7481B44; from=<> to=<support@MYDOMAIN.TLD.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<EUR04-VI1-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com>
Dec 13 16:41:23 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: disconnect from unknown[52.100.19.27] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 bdat=1 quit=1 commands=7
Dec 13 16:41:48 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: connect from mail-db3eur04hn0239.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.17.239]
Dec 13 16:41:48 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-db3eur04hn0239.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.17.239]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Dec 13 16:41:48 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: NOQUEUE: client=mail-db3eur04hn0239.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.17.239]
Dec 13 16:41:52 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724352]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 13 16:41:52 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724352]: 4675481B44: client=localhost[127.0.0.1], orig_client=mail-db3eur04hn0239.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.17.239]
Dec 13 16:41:52 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724352]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 xforward=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=6
Dec 13 16:41:52 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: proxy-accept: END-OF-MESSAGE: 250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4675481B44; from=<> to=<support@MYDOMAIN.TLD.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<EUR04-DB3-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com>
Dec 13 16:41:52 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: disconnect from mail-db3eur04hn0239.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.17.239] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 bdat=1 quit=1 commands=7
Dec 13 16:42:14 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: connect from mail-he1eur04hn0243.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.18.243]
Dec 13 16:42:14 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-he1eur04hn0243.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.18.243]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Dec 13 16:42:14 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: NOQUEUE: client=mail-he1eur04hn0243.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.18.243]
Dec 13 16:42:18 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724352]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 13 16:42:18 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724352]: 8E1DC81B44: client=localhost[127.0.0.1], orig_client=mail-he1eur04hn0243.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.18.243]
Dec 13 16:42:18 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724352]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 xforward=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=6
Dec 13 16:42:18 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: proxy-accept: END-OF-MESSAGE: 250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 8E1DC81B44; from=<> to=<support@MYDOMAIN.TLD.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<EUR04-HE1-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com>
Dec 13 16:42:18 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: disconnect from mail-he1eur04hn0243.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.18.243] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 bdat=1 quit=1 commands=7
Dec 13 16:42:22 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: connect from mail-db5eur01hn2219.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.6.219]
Dec 13 16:42:22 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-db5eur01hn2219.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.6.219]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Dec 13 16:42:22 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: NOQUEUE: client=mail-db5eur01hn2219.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.6.219]
Dec 13 16:42:26 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724352]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 13 16:42:26 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724352]: 5C97481B44: client=localhost[127.0.0.1], orig_client=mail-db5eur01hn2219.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.6.219]
Dec 13 16:42:26 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: proxy-accept: END-OF-MESSAGE: 250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 5C97481B44; from=<> to=<support@MYDOMAIN.TLD.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<EUR01-DB5-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com>
Dec 13 16:42:26 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: disconnect from mail-db5eur01hn2219.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.6.219] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 bdat=1 quit=1 commands=7
Dec 13 16:42:35 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: connect from mail-db5eur03hn2225.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.12.225]
Dec 13 16:42:35 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-db5eur03hn2225.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.12.225]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Dec 13 16:42:35 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: NOQUEUE: client=mail-db5eur03hn2225.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.12.225]
Dec 13 16:42:39 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724352]: 386A981B44: client=localhost[127.0.0.1], orig_client=mail-db5eur03hn2225.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.12.225]
Dec 13 16:42:39 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: proxy-accept: END-OF-MESSAGE: 250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 386A981B44; from=<> to=<support@MYDOMAIN.TLD.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<EUR03-DB5-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com>
Dec 13 16:42:39 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: disconnect from mail-db5eur03hn2225.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.12.225] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 bdat=1 quit=1 commands=7
Dec 13 16:42:52 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: connect from mail-am6eur05hn2237.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.174.237]
Dec 13 16:42:52 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-am6eur05hn2237.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.174.237]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Dec 13 16:42:52 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: NOQUEUE: client=mail-am6eur05hn2237.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.174.237]
Dec 13 16:42:55 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724352]: ADC6C81B44: client=localhost[127.0.0.1], orig_client=mail-am6eur05hn2237.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.174.237]
Dec 13 16:42:55 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: proxy-accept: END-OF-MESSAGE: 250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as ADC6C81B44; from=<> to=<support@MYDOMAIN.TLD.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<EUR05-AM6-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com>
Dec 13 16:42:55 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: disconnect from mail-am6eur05hn2237.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.174.237] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 bdat=1 quit=1 commands=7
Dec 13 16:42:58 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: connect from mail-ve1eur01hn2225.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.7.225]
Dec 13 16:42:58 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-ve1eur01hn2225.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.7.225]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Dec 13 16:42:58 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: NOQUEUE: client=mail-ve1eur01hn2225.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.7.225]
Dec 13 16:43:01 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724352]: C64E481B44: client=localhost[127.0.0.1], orig_client=mail-ve1eur01hn2225.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.7.225]
Dec 13 16:43:02 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: proxy-accept: END-OF-MESSAGE: 250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as C64E481B44; from=<> to=<support@MYDOMAIN.TLD.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<EUR01-VE1-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com>
Dec 13 16:43:02 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: disconnect from mail-ve1eur01hn2225.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.7.225] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 bdat=1 quit=1 commands=7
```

grep 5C97481B44 /var/log/mail.log

```
Dec 13 16:42:26 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724352]: 5C97481B44: client=localhost[127.0.0.1], orig_client=mail-db5eur01hn2219.outbound.protection.outlook.com[52.100.6.219]
Dec 13 16:42:26 v220200481250113989 postfix/cleanup[2724293]: 5C97481B44: message-id=<ef48be11-43ae-45c1-b85a-5802aeddc443@AM0PR06MB4228.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com>
Dec 13 16:42:26 v220200481250113989 opendkim[1485]: 5C97481B44: no signing table match for 'postmaster@bagir.com'
Dec 13 16:42:26 v220200481250113989 opendkim[1485]: 5C97481B44: signature=n/tVvyjz domain=bagirgroup.onmicrosoft.com selector=selector2-bagirgroup-onmicrosoft-com result="no signature error"
Dec 13 16:42:26 v220200481250113989 opendkim[1485]: 5C97481B44: DKIM verification successful
Dec 13 16:42:26 v220200481250113989 opendkim[1485]: 5C97481B44: s=selector2-bagirgroup-onmicrosoft-com d=bagirgroup.onmicrosoft.com a=rsa-sha256 SSL
Dec 13 16:42:26 v220200481250113989 postfix/qmgr[2724281]: 5C97481B44: from=<>, size=90649, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 13 16:42:26 v220200481250113989 amavis[2697255]: (2697255-15) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInbound}, [52.100.6.219]:53760 [52.100.6.219] <> -> <support@MYDOMAIN.TLD>, Message-ID: <ef48be11-43ae-45c1-b85a-5802aeddc443@am0pr06mb4228.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com>, mail_id: waxgkYX0CzYk, Hits: 1.539, size: 90045, queued_as: 5C97481B44, dkim_sd=selector2-bagirgroup-onmicrosoft-com:bagirgroup.onmicrosoft.com, 3620 ms
Dec 13 16:42:26 v220200481250113989 postfix/lmtp[2724353]: 5C97481B44: to=<support@MYDOMAIN.TLD>, relay=mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.17, delays=0.16/0/0.01/0, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 550 5.1.1 <support@MYDOMAIN.TLD> User doesn't exist: support@MYDOMAIN.TLD (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Dec 13 16:42:26 v220200481250113989 postfix/qmgr[2724281]: 5C97481B44: removed
Dec 13 16:42:26 v220200481250113989 postfix/smtpd[2724317]: proxy-accept: END-OF-MESSAGE: 250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 5C97481B44; from=<> to=<support@MYDOMAIN.TLD> proto=ESMTP helo=<EUR01-DB5-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com>
```

What could it be and how can I fix it?

Comment: The log entries you posted are logs for lmtp, so they are for mail delivered to local accounts on your server, not sent out from your server. Provide the log entries for actual messages sent from your server. They should include an IP address of the source of these messages. Also ask on postfix-users mailing list, it's the best place for Postfix support: http://www.postfix.org/lists.html

Comment: Hi @raj , I added the logs in the starting post.

I receive a lot of undelivarable mails from the postermasters to my catch all postbox. the support@MYDOMAIN.TLD doensn't exist

Comment: This still looks like your server is receiving those e-mails, not sending them. The messages come from outlook.com servers. `from=<> to=<support@MYDOMAIN.TLD.de>` in the logs suggests that these are - as you say - bounces of messages sent from (nonexistent) support@MYDOMAIN.TLD.de address to outlook.com. The original messages may have been sent from anywhere in the world with fake sender address, and outlook.com is returning them back to you.

Comment: Hi, in postfix configuration you have `myhostname = mail.MYDOMAIN.TLD`. You mask this? Change this with real domain.

Comment: Hi @2707974 , yes it's masked. The original domain belongs to my small business.

Comment: thanks @raj !
That's quite suprising. This domain isn't so old and I can't imagine why someone should use this as fake sender address.